# Gitlab CI rule for when changes are ONLY selected files

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to modify an existing gitlab CI pipeline so that the "deploy" stage will not fire if the merge request's list of changed files is unrelated to the actual code being deployed.

```
 deploy:
   extends: .standard_template
   only:
     - master
     - main
```

Right now deploy only occurs only on master or main branches and I'd like to continue that same logic, but I would also like to introduce the additional logic that if the ONLY thing changed is readme.md then don't do the deploy.

I've seen gitlabs support for the `changes:` rule, that appears to expect a matching subset of the listed files. What I want is to match a full set of `readme.md` and abort/not start the deploy.

Is this possible with gitlab's syntax? I know I could write additional "jobs" to do my own `script:` rules do stuff with the git-tree to inspect changes, but then I have to exit 1 to basically cause the pipeline to fail, which leads to a bunch of red failures or incomplete jobs in the build, when what I really want is just to omit this portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a couple of [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

```yaml
deploy:
  extends: .standard_template
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"
      when: never
    - changes:
        - readme.md
      when: never
    - when: always
```

The first rule is the same as your `only: main or master` clause. If `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is anything other than `main` or `master`, it won't add the job to the pipeline.

The second rule looks to see if there are changes to the `readme.md` file, but explicitly adds a `when` condition: *never*.

The third rule is our default case if the first two don't match.

All together this is, don't run if the branch isn't main/master, don't run if there are changes to the readme, otherwise always run.

Note: You'll likely have to extend this a bit since this doesn't account for Tag pipelines, merge request pipelines, etc., but that's simple to do with some additional rules.

Comment: Thanks, but the 2nd phase of this pipeline is incorrect. If someone touches code and the readme I do want to deploy that code. My condition I'm looking for is if someone touches ONLY readme.md, then we don't need to deploy.

Comment: In that case, what you’re looking for is more complex than the `changes` rule can solve. It’s not meant to solve all use cases, so in situations like these I’d remove the rule and implement that logic yourself in a `before_script` clause.